# How can I draw a line to the right in pine script with "plot"?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want the drawn lines to extend to the right without interruptions

currently they stay up to a certain point and do not advance further

The idea is to mark the supports and resistances from behind

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='Test029', shorttitle='Test029', overlay=true)

//Input
exhaustionSwitch = input(true, title='Show exhaustion Bar point (Arrows)')
levelSwitch = input(true, title='Show exhaustion levels (Lines)')
length = input(40, 'Exhaustions swing length')
bars = input(10, 'Exhaustion bar count')
thicknesSwitch = input(2, title='Line Thickness(Level thickness)')

//Fun Lele
test(bars, len) =>
    bindex = int(na)
    bindex := nz(bindex[1], 0)
    sindex = int(na)
    sindex := nz(sindex[1], 0)

    return_1 = 0
    bindex := close > close[4] ? bindex + 1 : bindex
    sindex := close < close[4] ? sindex + 1 : sindex
    if bindex > bars and close < open and high >= ta.highest(high, len)
        bindex := 0
        return_1 := -1
        return_1
    else
        if sindex > bars and close > open and low <= ta.lowest(low, len)
            sindex := 0
            return_1 := 1
            return_1

//Out C
testx = test(bars, length)

//Out Bar 
highlel = testx == -1 ? high : na
lowlel = testx == 1 ? low : na

//Out level
resistance = float(na)
support = float(na)
resistance := close < open and testx ? high : resistance[1]
support := close > open and testx ? low : support[1]

//Color 
rescol = color.new(#ff0000, 1)
highcol = ta.change(resistance) == 0 ? rescol : na
supcol = color.new(#138484, 1)
lowcol = ta.change(support) == 0 ? supcol : na

//Plot level
plot(levelSwitch ? resistance : na, title='Reistance Level', style=plot.style_line, color=highcol, linewidth=thicknesSwitch)
plot(levelSwitch ? support : na, title='Support Level', style=plot.style_line, color=lowcol, linewidth=thicknesSwitch)

line.new(bar_index[bars], support, bar_index, support, extend=extend.right, color=color.yellow)
line.new(bar_index[bars], resistance, bar_index, resistance, extend=extend.right, color=color.yellow)

alertcondition(lowlel, 'Up')
alertcondition(highlel, 'Down')
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeoST.png)

I tried it with line.new but it only takes the last value, it doesn't take the previous values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are using `plot()` to draw your lines. It will only have one value for its series argument.

You need to use `line.new()` with `extend=extend.right` every time you find a new support or resistance. But doing so will give you MANY lines so you may want to delete older ones after some point.

## Edit:

You need to first figure out if there is a new support or resistance. You can do that by comparing their values with their previous values.

Only draw a new line when it is a new support or resistance.

```
new_support = support != support[1]
new_resistance = resistance != resistance[1]

if (new_support)
    line.new(bar_index, support, bar_index + 1, support, extend=extend.right, color=color.yellow)

if (new_resistance)
    line.new(bar_index, resistance, bar_index + 1, resistance, extend=extend.right, color=color.yellow)
```

Also, you probably want to have something like `max_lines_count = 10` in your `indicaotr()` call otherwise your chart will have way too many lines.

Comment: I tried it with line.new but it only takes the last value, the yellow line is made with line.new and the red and green lines with plot :

line.new(bar_index[bars], support, bar_index, support, extend=extend.right, color=color.yellow)
line.new(bar_index[bars], resistance, bar_index, resistance, extend=extend.right, color=color.yellow)

alertcondition(lowlel, 'Up')
alertcondition(highlel, 'Down')

Comment: That's because you are creating the lines without any condition. See my edit please.